# How to actually display calendars imported from google other than the main one?

Tags: 8.0, calendars, google

I use google calendar on regular basis and I have separate calendars for different things (like one for appointments, one for classes, one for anniversaries etc.).

I've recently acquired a Windows Phone 8 device (a HTC 8S) and managed to get it to sync with Google without much trouble (other than obvious ones like poor gmail support and lack of g+ support). However, all the events from calendars other than the main one never appear anywhere in the calendar or as notifications.

That is despite the fact that when I go into settings, I can apparently turn those other calendars off (they're on) and on as well as change their display color, so I'm not even sure if this is a sync problem or something else altogether. Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

I know that a similar question has been asked both [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/179/1779) and elsewhere, but none of the solutions listed seem to work. If I log in at m.google.com/sync with the Windows Phone, it doesn't even load. Loading it with iPad user agent and js disabled doesn't show any device list.

Is there any way to display the other calendars anymore?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to accomplish this directly, however, I've found a partial workaround:

1. First, you log in to live.com calendar and subscribe to those calendars on Google which you want to show up on your phone (you can find information on how to do that exactly on the internet, for example [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-sync-windows-live-and-google-calendar/).
2. Then, you sync calendars from live.com with your phone and voila! All your Google calendars are available on your phone.
3. You may want to disable (direct) calendar syncing with Google on your phone to avoid clutter in your calendar apps.

The problem with this solution is that it only allows you to view the calendars, not actually edit them, and the sync can take some time (live.com only syncs with external calendars once daily or every second day) but I think it's good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that worked for WP 8.1 at [this site](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpemail/shared-google-calendar-not-syncing-with-windows/69bf4b61-7df0-4116-b815-b53ad5069a8e). Quote:

> To get shared calendars visible from my Google account, I had to use Google's online Calendar sync management tool. Depending on your account and how it syncs (Exchange or CalDav), you need to visit one of these pages on your mobile device:
>
> https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect (if you're using CalDAV, like a "normal" consumer Gmail account), or, <snip>
>
> On those pages are the Calendar sync settings which list the calendars available to sync, with checkboxes to select them.

You then have to wait for the next sync, or force syncing through Settings > Email & Accounts > Long-press *Google*, and select *Synchronize*